# multiple mysql select queries

Tags: mysql

I have an array with zipcodes indexed by distance. now i need to select pizza shops 
based on the zips, some thing like:

```
ziparray[]

foreach loop

SELECT * FROM location WHERE food='pizza' and zip='ziparray[]'

//do stuff
```

The zip array can grow up to 30 or 40 zips in time, which means 30 or 40 querys.
Is there a better way to do this? i'm hoping to figure out Stored Procedures
this way I can just send the parms in and have it send back the data(if i can).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM location
WHERE food='pizza'
  and zip IN(90210, 55555, etc..)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using [IN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) operator?

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (value1,value2,...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider transforming that array into an IN clause, such that your query
becomes SELECT * FROM location WHERE food='pizza' and zip in ('03750','03532', .. other 50 zip codes)

Answer (score 0):

you could construct a query using a for loop. here's an example in PHP:

```
$zipArray = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM location WHERE food='pizza' AND ( 1=2";


foreach($zipArray as $zip){
  $query .= "OR zip ='$zip' ";
}
```

$query .= ")";

the 1=2 part is a little sloppy, you could add an OR at the end of each addition in the foreach loop and use some function to cut off the last part of the string.